# Disabling Triggers for a PHP script with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

i'm working with a medium size DB in MySQL, and i'm updating model. 
This Db have various tables strictly correlated, and use Foreign Keys and Triggers for updating related data.
Now i'm working on a PHP script to pass data from the old to the new database model, and i have a little problem with triggers.
For all life of the DB the triggers will stay and work well, but i need, before it, to load the data with the triggers turned off. 
Cleanest solution for me is to disable all the Triggers before loading the data, and turn it back on at the end of the procedure... How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to disable triggers (see [Triggers: enable or disable](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2825)).

What you can do is modify your triggers to check for session variable (eg. @triggers_disabled) and if's set, do nothing.

Comment: Well, but i don't want to ask for each query if the triggers are disabled, when i need to do it only in first session, during data migration. Maybe could be better if I drop all the tables and recreate it before migrate data and move triggers creation after data migration?

Comment: That's different then. You should initially create your tables without triggers, and add them after migration.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Before migration database is clean, so best solution could be create tables before migration and add triggers after.